# Output using two dictionaries not as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe using two dictionaries, one for its column values and one for its data values. I need to do this because my data is dynamic and cannot be hardcoded.

Pandas is not outputting my data correctly, it outputs both the keys and the vals as data.

**My Dictionaries**

My dictionaries look something like this.

Note: keys and vals are dynamically populated by a scraper, values below are just for example purposes.

```
keys = {' Animal, Vegetable, Mineral '}
vals = {' Dog, Carrot, Diamond '}
```

**My attempt**

```
keys = []
vals = []

df5 = pd.DataFrame([keys,vals])

df5.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Pandas-Example2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
writer.save()
```

**Expected result**

My output should look like this

```
Animal    Vegetable    Mineral
Dog       Carrot       Diamond
```

**Actual result**

But I get this

```
 0           1            2        
Animal    Vegetable    Mineral
Dog       Carrot       Diamond
```

Comment: `keys` and `values` are defined as sets under your "My Dictionaries" section. They are then redefined as lists in your "My attempt" section. Please check and clarify.

Comment: The way you wrote it, you dont have any dictionary, but two sets with one element each?

Comment: @jpp No, no I did not hardcode those values, they are dynamically populated at runtime. When I declare them, they are just blank.

Comment: @Ninja2k, Then why does your question say `My dictionaries look something like this.`? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want parameter columns in `DataFrame` contructor with lists in `keys` and `vals`:

```
keys = ['Animal', 'Vegetable', 'Mineral']
vals = ['Dog', 'Carrot', 'Diamond']

df5 = pd.DataFrame([vals], columns=keys)
print (df5)
  Animal Vegetable  Mineral
0    Dog    Carrot  Diamond
```

Comment: I could have sworn I already tried this! That works fine, thank you.